# Copy and Paste Filtered rows in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

I am trying to copy and paste some rows of a filtered table to a range of cells in Excel. As a filter has been applied, the rows to be copied are now always the same.
I am trying to paste the copied rows on to cell O2.
I have tried to do it this way:

```
Dim Rows As Range
Rows = Sheet10.Range("B10:B")
With Rows
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheet10.Range("O2")
End With
  End Sub
```

When doing it this way, I always get error 1004: "Method'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed". The same error pops when I tried it this way:

```
Dim Rows As Range
Rows = Sheet10.Range("B10:B")
With Sheet10.Range("B10:B")
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheet10.Range("O2")
End With
  End Sub
```

I am new to VBA and I think I might be missing some basic object rules. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Range address should be `B10:B100`;
- Use the `Set` word, when you set
  a range;
- Do not use `Rows` as a variable word, it is used in VBA;
- Use    `Worksheets`, not `Sheets`, it is a bit better;
- Use `Option Explicit` on top.

Like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim rngRows As Range

    Set rngRows = Worksheets(8).Range("B10:B100")
    With rngRows
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(8).Range("O2")
    End With

End Sub
```